# Neither A nor B

Tags: formality, negation, lists, neither-nor

As a native speaker, the basic usage of "neither" and "nor" are perfectly clear to me. However, natives may suffer from colloquial usage sounding more normal than formal grammar. I definitely have that with this one. I am not entirely sure whether the following sentences are technically correct, which is due to the lack of "neither", normally used to negate, in these sentences:

1. A nor B is not true.

   - (There is a negation in there, but this sounds strange to me.)
2. A nor B is true.

   - (Sound better, as though the "neither" is merely skipped, but I imagine this might be the one that is technically wrong.)
3. A nor B nor C is true.
4. A nor B nor C is not true.

It would be nice to hear from someone who is really sure about these things, as opposed to me only judging by the sound of it.

Cheers.

Comment: All of (1-4) are ungrammatical; you can't delete _neither_ that easily. _Nor_ by itself has other uses, e.g _I haven't seen her, nor have I talked to her_, which means _I haven't seen her, and I haven't  talked to her._ DeMorgan's Laws are part of English, it appears.

Comment: I think once you get beyond non-trivial logic, English sentences become very awkward, and it's better to use mathematical logic notation.

Comment: @JohnLawler
You have my intuition's full support. "Nor A nor B is true" is merely a matter of replacing "Neither" with "Nor", but one cannot omit both as I have done above, I would say. Both A and B have to be negated and this is done with neither, nor or a not + verb. 

Nor A nor B is true  =  Neither A nor B is true  !=  A nor B is true.
Nor A nor B is not true = Neither A nor B is not true != A nor B is not true.

The latter set is rather silly and cumbersome, but I'm interested in the effect of the negation "is not".

Would you agree with my conclusion?

Comment: @k1eran
Agreed, hence maths.

Comment: @JGTP: I'm afraid I can't agree, because I don't know what your conclusion is. Not all the sentences you cite are grammatical English, so their value in an argument is not clear. BTW, _is not_ is not "a negation". _Is_ is an auxiliary verb for predicate nouns and adjectives; _not_ is a negative. They can (and almost always do) get contracted to _isn't_; saying _is not_ without contraction marks a local context with special rules and meanings (like mathematics or law). As to the scope of negation, that varies like the scopes of modals and quantifiers; they're all operators.

Comment: Duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106795/using-nor-without-neither-special-case?rq=1